# Powershell ADD-VpnConnection works incorrectly when using preshared key

Tags: powershell

I have created a Powershell script (V. 5) to add a VPN connection in Windows 10, the issue is that the preshared key is not stored correctly.

```
$mypsk = "someCharsHere"
Add-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection -Name myVPN -ServerAddress some.address.here -TunnelType L2tp -EncryptionLevel Optional -L2tpPsk $mypsk -AuthenticationMethod Chap,MSChapv2 -RememberCredential -SplitTunneling -Force -DnsSuffix a.dns.suffix -UseWinlogonCredential
```

The script above will correctly create a connection entry, however attempting to connect, will not work, there's a long delay ending with an error:

> "The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer
>   encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the
>   remote computer"

BUT, when opening connection properties and manually pasting the preshared key in the connection properties and saving, *voilà*, the connection will work.

[image]

I assume somehow the preshared key is not saved correctly somehow.... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Go it to work, 
special characters in string! Using single quotes solved the problem!